# Updating pip not working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am unable to update pip in ubuntu.I've ubuntu 14.04 64-bit,Python 3.6 and anaconda3 installed in my machine. I've used the following command to  update pip.
           sudo apt-get update 
I've tried the following solutions
    In etc/hosts added the following 
    91.189.88.46    us.archive.ubuntu.com
    91.189.88.46    security.ubuntu.com
    91.189.88.46    *.ubuntu.com

```
But still getting the error as
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                          
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                        
Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease  
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease  
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease  
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease  
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Tried running the command pip install --upgrade pip but it throws error.

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 487, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install, finder)
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 428, in _check_skip_installed
    req_to_install, upgrade_allowed)
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 390, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 290, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 184, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs
  File "/home/tcs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 43, in SOCKSProxyManager
    raise InvalidSchema("Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.")
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.

Comment: Have you tried:
pip install --upgrade pip

?

Comment: I think this would be more suited for http://askubuntu.com/.

Comment: @ma3oun I tried pip install --upgrade pip but it gives an error. I've updated the question to show the output.